# Redeclaration error while initializing static member

Tags: c++, class, static-members

I made a class,and there is some static member in it.

I Googled "how initializing static member", and I learned that I should initialize the static member outside the class.

But, I got a redeclaration error while initializing static member.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

using namespace std;
class Color
{
public:
int r,g,b;
Color();
Color(int r_,int g_,int b_)
{
r=r_;
g=g_;
b=g_;
}
static Color Red;
};

int main()
{
Color Color::Red=Color(255,0,0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, for pity's sake, include the code, not a huge picture with sub-microscopic code scrunched up in a corner of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize your Static members like this.

```
class class_name {
    static int i;
};
int class_name::i = 0;
```

This is needed because your class can only have one instance of i. 
however For the constant variables you can do this directly in your class.

```
class class_name {
    static int i;
    const static int j = 20;

};
```

**EDIT**:
Section 6.7 of the standard has this to say:

> The zero-initialization of all local objects with static storage
>   duration is performed before any other initialization takes place. A
>   local object of POD type with static storage duration initialized with
>   constant-expressions is initialized before its block is first entered.
>   An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of
>   other local objects with static storage duration under the same
>   conditions that an implementation is permitted to statically
>   initialize an object with static storage duration in namespace scope.
>   Otherwise such an object is initialized the first time control passes
>   through its declaration; such an object is considered initialized upon
>   the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits by
>   throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it will
>   be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. If
>   control re-enters the declaration (recursively) while the object is
>   being initialized, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thank you!.But why do I get a redeclaration error in main()? What 's the difference when initialization is outside the main()?

Comment: Thank you for your information, yet it is still  little confusing to me

Answer (score 3):

Try to move it out of `main()`.

```
...
Color Color::Red = Color(255, 0, 0);
int main() 
{
...
```

Comment: Thank you! It does work now.But why do I get a redeclaration error in main()? What 's the difference when initialization is outside the main()?

Comment: @user3094631 Static member can't be defined in a function. I guess your compiler just treat it as a declaration, and then cause a redeclaration error.

Comment: @user3094631 [Here](http://rextester.com/ZEKS77541) you can see the clang compiler's error message for it, just as a reference.